# Yocto use boot-efi-ia32 but x64 linux kernel

Tags: x86, yocto

Is it possible to use x64-kernel&rootfs with the efi-ia32? (machine has 64 cpu but doesn't support x64efi)

I mean: my intent is set machine = "intel-corei7-64" but not with grub-efi x64. I want to install only grub-efi as 32 bit with the set yocto metadatas.

(Excuse me for my english I am not native)

Thank you.

Comment: I'd assume so.  GRUB just needs to load the kernel image, and 32 vs. 64-bit x86 kernels use the same image format.  The Linux kernel takes care of switching to 64-bit mode and decompressing itself.  A 32-bit EFI bootloader should not be a problem.

Comment: Mr. Cordes
So how I can install efi-ia32 to yocto configuration which i select machine="intel-corei7-64" because when I select 64 bit, it does install exactly x64 which the system doesn't boot.

Comment: I have no clue, I don't use yocto.